# non-polar electrolytics made with polarized caps

Tags: capacitor

With reference to Oli Glaser's diagram of the series-connected polarized caps with the diodes across them. If this arrangement were applied to a high-voltage B+ power supply in a tube circuit, would there be a voltage consideration for the diodes?

Atom

Comment: Do you think we're clairvoyant?? If you're referring to another question/answer, could you *please* include a link? Now we don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: Steven is right, and he shouldn't have to ask. *It is difficult to tell what is being asked here*.

Comment: @AtomShop English, Do you speak it MF? This question is vague, unclear and poorly phrased.

Answer (score 1):

THe Peak Inverse Voltage of the Diodes and the CAp rated voltage should be 20% or so more than nominal design worst case B+ for reliability margin.

Comment: If you agree then accept, if you dont say why, if not understand say ?? , but do make a decision. But both Diode and Cap must be rated much higher than B+

Comment: You cannot even daisy chain Caps under rated for voltage in series. Because the leaky Cap will cause the other caps to take most of the voltage in a string. Each cap if used in series, polar or not, must be rated for worst case drop.